# How do I encrypt data that I transmit from my Android app?

Tags: android, encryption

I have a question about the encryption of transmitted data. I have a client-server application. The application from time to time (4-8-12 h) sends to server data via the Internet. My problem is that this data require encrypted in such a way that nobody could steal it. How can I encrypt the data?. Can someone who has experience in this field could show me in the right way? I will only add that the application will run on Android and the server are written in Java. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bruce Schneier's [Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html) is a good introduction to the theory and practice of cryptography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a cheap and easy way to communicate securely with your server, use the [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) class. The android development team has actually put a lot of time and effort into this class. It has good performance and has tons of cool capabilities. For more info, checkout this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).